# Bash script aggregating similar fields

Tags: bash, sorting, count, awk, aggregate

I have the following data which by column is `IP`, `PORT` and `Bytes`. I would like to total bytes based on similar `IP` and `Port`. So where `Port` and `IP's` are the same total the bytes and then in the end sort based on `bytes` and `ports` so in the end I can get the top 10 talkers per `port` sorted by `bytes`.

So with the data below the top talkers for port 80 would be:

```
174.143.121.217 80 30722
109.108.151.126 80 25083
```

Then the top talkers for port 5989 would be:

```
192.168.23.20 5989 26601
```

The file:

```
208.76.128.67 443 2975
204.154.110.99 80 1713
130.117.119.220 80 845
192.168.23.20 5989 26601
23.15.8.35 80 33944
64.69.6.116 443 5936
208.76.128.67 443 2309
66.129.120.117 80 1514
208.76.128.67 443 4143
109.108.151.126 80 3589
109.108.151.126 80 21494
174.143.121.217 80 30722
173.45.233.170 80 2218
66.235.155.28 80 4367
64.94.107.50 80 1236
76.13.114.90 80 534
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`, `sort` and `column -t` for a nice table formatted ouput:

```
awk '{a[$1" "$2]=a[$1" "$2]+$3}END{for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' file |
> sort -nk2 -rnk3 |
> column -t 
192.168.23.20    5989  26601
208.76.128.67    443   9427
64.69.6.116      443   5936
23.15.8.35       80    33944
174.143.121.217  80    30722
109.108.151.126  80    25083
66.235.155.28    80    4367
173.45.233.170   80    2218
204.154.110.99   80    1713
66.129.120.117   80    1514
64.94.107.50     80    1236
130.117.119.220  80    845
76.13.114.90     80    534
```

**Edit**:

To limit to the top 10 per port you could pipe to `awk 'c[$2]++<10'`. Demo *(limiting to top 4)*:

```
$ awk '{a[$1" "$2]=a[$1" "$2]+$3}END{for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' file |
> sort -nk2 -rnk3 |
> column -t |
> awk 'c[$2]++<4' 
192.168.23.20    5989  26601
208.76.128.67    443   9427
64.69.6.116      443   5936
23.15.8.35       80    33944
174.143.121.217  80    30722
109.108.151.126  80    25083
66.235.155.28    80    4367
```

Comment: Thank you ... I had to edit my post because I am also looking to group based on port then sort based on bytes ... so I can identify the top 10 talkers for port 80 then sort by bytes greatest to least, then move to the next port 443 (top 10 talkers) sorted greatest to least and so on...